Vuetify v-form Form Validation Not Working in Vitest
I'm currently writing tests for a Vue3 + Vuetify website with Vitest.
The website uses Vuetify components and one of the components I'm testing includes a v-form component. Here is the component code:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

const firstName = ref("");
const lastName = ref("");
const email = ref("");
const company = ref("");
const lang = ref("");
const valid = ref(false);

const emailRegex = RegExp(
    /[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?/
);

const firstNameRules = [
    (value: string) => {
        if (value) return true;
        return "First Name Required";
    }
];

const lastNameRules = [
    (value: string) => {
        if (value) return true;
        return "Last Name Required";
    }
];

const emailRules = [
    (value: string) => {
        if (value) return true;
        return "Email Required";
    },
    (value: string) => {
        if (emailRegex.test(value)) return true;
        return "Email Not Valid";
    }
];

const companyRules = [
    (value: string) => {
        if (value) return true;
        return "Company Required";
    }
];

const languageRules = [
    (value: string) => {
        if (value) return true;
        return "Language Required";
    }
];

</script>

<template>
    <v-card>
        <v-card-text>
            <v-form v-model="valid">
                <v-row>
                    <v-col>
                        <v-text-field
                            data-testid="first-name-input"
                            v-model="firstName"
                            :rules="firstNameRules"
                            label="First Name"
                        ></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col>
                        <v-text-field
                            data-testid="last-name-input"
                            v-model="lastName"
                            :rules="lastNameRules"
                            label="Last Name"
                        ></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row dense>
                    <v-col>
                        <v-text-field
                            data-testid="email-input"
                            v-model="email"
                            :rules="emailRules"
                            label="Email"
                        ></v-text-field>
                        <v-text-field
                            data-testid="company-input"
                            v-model="company"
                            :rules="companyRules"
                            label="Company"
                        ></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row dense>
                    <v-radio-group
                        data-testid="lang-input"
                        v-model="lang"
                        :rules="languageRules"
                    >
                        <v-label>Invite Language"</v-label>

                        <v-radio label="French" value="fr"></v-radio>

                        <v-radio label="English" value="en"></v-radio>

                    </v-radio-group>
                </v-row>
            </v-form>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>

            <v-btn data-testid="cancel-btn"></v-btn>

            <v-btn data-testid="create-btn" :disabled="!valid"></v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</template>

The form validation in this component works correctly when I test it by hand with my test data (included in following test), but the following test doesn't work:
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";

import { describe, it, expect } from "vitest";

import CreatePollForm from "../CreatePollForm.vue";

import { createTestingPinia } from "@pinia/testing";
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";

describe("CreatePollForm", () => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        components,
        directives
    });

    it("Button is enabled on valid form", async () => {
        const wrapper = mount(CreatePollForm, {
            global: {
                plugins: [createTestingPinia(), vuetify],
                mocks: {
                    $t: (message: string) => message
                }
            }
        });
        // This line works as expected: disabled == ''
        expect(wrapper.find("[data-testid='create-btn']").attributes().disabled).toBeDefined();
        await wrapper.find("[data-testid='first-name-input']").find("input").setValue("ABC");
        await wrapper.find("[data-testid='last-name-input']").find("input").setValue("abc");
        await wrapper.find("[data-testid='email-input']").find("input").setValue("A@B.C");
        await wrapper.find("[data-testid='company-input']").find("input").setValue("AbC");
        await wrapper.find("[data-testid='lang-input']").find("input").trigger("click");

        // Here, disabled should be undefined but it is still equal to ''
        expect(wrapper.find("[data-testid='create-btn']").attributes().disabled).toBeUndefined();
    });
});


I've tried adding some wrapper.vm.$nextTick() to no avail.
I suspect that the problem lies in the radio-group since I tried checking the html before and after selection in my browser and I never saw any checked or selected attribute for the radio buttons.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.
